# What is the best way to shuffle the results that come back from a Graph query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, typescript

I have an SPFx web part for SPO which gets the members of a team. What's the best way to shuffle the 'result' data that comes back?

**EDIT**: I have tried this:
`result = result.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)`
but it returns error:

> "n.sort is not a function"

```
var client = await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3');
    //var result = await client.api('groups/guid/members').get();
    console.log('this.properties.groupGUID:' + this.properties.groupGUID)
    var result = await client.api('groups/' + this.properties.groupGUID + '/members').get();
    console.log(result);
    result = result.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
```

Comment: Can you explain your requirements in detail? Why you want to shuffle the results? Do you want to shuffle data based on any specific property or what?

Comment: I just want to randomize the order of the results as they are returned.

Comment: Try using [_.shuffle function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle) in lodash library. Let me know if it works for you. Also, try using sort or shuffle on `value` array available inside returned results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [_.shuffle function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle) available in lodash library.

Use code like this:

```
var result = await client.api('groups/' + this.properties.groupGUID + '/members').get();
const graphResponse: any = response.value;  
const shuffledGraphResponse: any = _.shuffle(graphResponse);
```

Comment: You can also find other methods for same at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array/18650169#18650169

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks Ganesh

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!